# Ajuda numa query em Ruby on Rails

Tags: query, ruby-on-rails

Boa tarde, eu começei a trabalhar com Rails há pouco tempo e estou a ter dificuldades com uma query. Estou a construir uma Api em que tenho o model Game e o model User. Um user tem vários games, e um game tem dois users (existindo uma tabela intermedia GameUsers). Ao usar a consola do rails, eu consigo ver fácilmente os users de um jogo fazendo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

83 e 84 são os ids dos users que pertencem a esse game. Mas se eu fizer
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo fazer uma query que me devolva os games a que pertencem dois users. Alguém me pode ajudar com isto? Obrigado

**Atualização**

Depois de algum tempo acabei por descobrir que seria `Game.joins(:users).where(users: { id:  [83 && 84] })`

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso você precisa fazer um `joins` com a tabela `users`.

`Game.joins(:users).where(users: { id:  [83, 84] })`.

Dê uma olhada nessas seções do guia sobre [Active Record Query Interface](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) para ter uma base melhor:

- [Conditions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions);
- [Joining Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins).

Comment: Obrigado a tua resposta ajudou-me, mas nessa querry são os jogos do user 83 OU 84. A resposta seria `Game.joins(:users).where(users: { id:  [83 && 84] })`.

Comment: A sua query não está fazendo o que você acha que está fazendo, executa essa query que comentou e a que eu mencionei na resposta e veja a diferença na query SQL gerada. No seu caso, está usando somente o ID 83 na query, porque [83 && 84] resulta em [83]. Enfim, não entendi muito bem a sua intenção, mas fico feliz que a resposta tenha te ajudado.